# tsql create XML with multiple records and 1 table node

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I have the following code:

```
    declare @Temp Table(FirstName varchar(50)
            ,LastName varchar(50))
    insert into @Temp values
    ('John','Smith'),
    ('William','Robert'),
    ('Richard','Rich'),
    ('Seymour','Code'),
    ('Hans','Hustler');

    Select
        (Select LastName + ',' + FirstName as [Name] from @Temp for XML                 PATH('names'), TYPE)
```

and it produces the following XML:

```
    <names>
      <Name>Smith,John</Name>
    </names>
    <names>
      <Name>Robert,William</Name>
    </names>
    <names>
      <Name>Rich,Richard</Name>
    </names>
    <names>
      <Name>Code,Seymour</Name>
    </names>
    <names>
      <Name>Hustler,Hans</Name>
    </names>
```

I need it to produce XML like the following:

```
    <names>
      <Name>Smith,John</Name>
      <Name>Robert,William</Name>
      <Name>Rich,Richard</Name>
      <Name>Code,Seymour</Name>
      <Name>Hustler,Hans</Name>
    </names>
```

Without a Names after every Name?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    Name = LastName + ', ' + FirstName
FROM @Temp 
    FOR XML PATH(''), ROOT('names')
```

This should return what you're looking for

Comment: You were faster :-) +1 from my side

Comment: That is exactly what I am looking for.  This is actually a component within a larger select statement and I thought the ROOT was only for the last ROOT.   Go to know!